# Exclude numerals from a custom counter environment

Tags: environments, counters

I have my document set up so that examples are numbered but I would prefer to be able to add my own number or title. I know I can add the title in square brackets, but how do I remove the numbers?

The code I am using to define `example`s is:

```
\newcounter{example}[subsection]

\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip

\textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is taken from user [ferahfeza](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31034/ferahfeza), but changed slightly in order to provide the correct label in case of referring to it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{example}[subsection]

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{exampleother}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}%
  \medskip

  \textbf{Example~#1 #2.} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{example}[2][]{%
  %\refstepcounter{example}
  \par\medskip
  \edef\@currentlabel{#2}%
  \textbf{Example~#1 #2.} \rmfamily}{\medskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
Solve \ref{foo} or \ref{foobar}

\begin{example}{35} \label{foo}
Solve the equation...
\end{example}

\begin{exampleother}{35} \label{foobar}
Solve the equation...
\end{exampleother}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MattBartlett: You're welcome -- happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{example}[subsection]
\newenvironment{example}[2][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
\textbf{Example~#1 #2.} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{example}{35}
Solve the equation...
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]